# Hotkeys quit working on server after some time using remote desktop connection

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

I am having an issue and I am not sure where it is coming from nor how to solve it.
Basically I am using mstsc on my laptop (windows 10) to connect on a desktop (windows 10) located in my office.

When the laptop is freshly started everything is working fine but after some times the hotkeys are not working anymore.
The issue seems to be related to the host because the only way to make it work again is to log off the laptop.
Tried couple of things :

- Restarted all services with %remote% in the name.
- Restart mstsc.
- Played with remote desktop settings.

Any help would be appreciate.
Thanks ;)

Comment: Which hotkeys stop working? Do other keys or key-combinations continue to work?

Comment: For instance the windows key will trigger the menu on the host not on the server. I am also using hotkeys for launchy (on both machines) and it will open on host.

Comment: Does the RDP perhaps lose the focus when hotkeys start working on the host? Have you tried clicking in RDP and trying the hotkey again?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not the focus, i tried close and restart the rdp it did not worked. And a restart of the server won't work either,  so far the only solution is just to log off (or restart) on host

Comment: I use RDP a lot and this never happened to me. Is it possible that some local application is stealing these keys?

Comment: I doubt it since the issue is coming from the host.

Comment: By "host" you mean the client, right?

Comment: Sorry i thought i answered you right away, yes i mean the client.

Comment: Is it just the Win key combinations, or also other keys?

Comment: I use 'ctrl + shift + space' for an app on both machines. It will trigger the one on the client.

Comment: Several programs use this shortcut, including Office for a non-breaking space, and others. I don't know which program you have that has hijacked the shortcut, but it might be better to change it to something less-used.

Comment: I don't think so. But thank you for taking the time that you did to give me your thoughts.